# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '2017-03-21'

Tags: sql, asp.net

```
protected void btnBeds_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    String checkBeds = "SELECT Count (*) FROM Bed WHERE bedID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(bedID) FROM Booking where startDate>='"+TxtArrivalDate.Text+"' and endDate<= '"+txtDepartureDate.Text+"'";
    SqlCommand showcheckBeds = new SqlCommand(checkBeds, con);
    ResultLabel.Text = showcheckBeds.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    con.Close();
}
```

I'm trying to display the amount of free beds there are in the database and im getting this error.

Comment: remove to '-' from the date, so you get startDate >= '20170321' and ...

Comment: Classic example of an SQL Injection risk. Of course, that's not your problem here - you just dropped a `)` at the end.

Comment: Parameterize your queries! Also, how about casting dates to `DATE`?

Answer (score 1):

1. Always use parameters in your queries
2. Always wrap connections and other types that implement `IDisposable` in `using` statements to ensure the resource is released
3. Use the correct types in your database and match that type with the passed in parameter. Example: do not pass in a string for a date, do not store dates as strings.

Your actual problem was a missing `)` at the end of your sql statement as pointed out by @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Updated code with changes:

```
const string checkBeds = "SELECT Count (*) FROM Bed WHERE bedID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(bedID) FROM Booking where startDate >= @startDate and endDate<= @endDate)";

using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
using(SqlCommand showcheckBeds = new SqlCommand(checkBeds, con))
{
    showcheckBeds.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@startDate", SqlDbType.DateTime){Value = DateTime.Parse(TxtArrivalDate.Text) });
    showcheckBeds.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@endDate", SqlDbType.DateTime){Value = DateTime.Parse(txtDepartureDate.Text) });
    con.Open();

    ResultLabel.Text = showcheckBeds.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
```

Note: In the code above I used a direct `DateTime.Parse` to get an actual `DateTime` instance to pass as a parameter. It would probably be advisable to change that either to `ParseExact` or to provide a `CultureInfo` instance to the method.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
String checkBeds = "SELECT Count (*) FROM Bed WHERE bedID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(bedID) FROM Booking where startDate>='"+Convert.ToDateTime( TxtArrivalDate.Text).ToStrin("dd MMM yyyy")+"' and endDate<= '"+Convert.ToDateTime(txtDepartureDate.Text).ToString("dd MMM yyyy")+"'";
```